# Eclipse GCC 5.0 Mac, make error: Abort trap 6

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, c++11, gcc

I'm trying to build a project I created in Eclipse using GCC 5.0 on a Mac.

I set up the environment variables for the project as:
CPATH:
${HOME}/gcc/include

LIBRARY_PATH:
${HOME|/gcc/lib

PATH:
${HOME}/gcc/bin:
 /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

I added -std=c++11 to the flags.

I added the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:
${env_var:HOME}/gcc/lib

However, when I build the project, I get the following error:

```
`Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [eulerclass.o] Abort trap: 6  Euler's Method          C/C++ Problem`
```

My CPP file is as follows:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

typedef double F(double,double);

/*
Approximates y(t) in y'(t)=f(t,y) with y(a)=y0 and
t=a..b and the step size h.
*/
void euler(F f, double y0, double a, double b, double h)
{
    double y = y0;
    for (double t = a; t < b; t += h)
    {
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << t << " " << y << "\n";
        y += h * f(t, y);
    }
    std::cout << "done\n";
}

// Example: Newton's cooling law
double newtonCoolingLaw(double, double t)
{
   return -0.07 * (t - 20);
}

int main()
{
    euler(newtonCoolingLaw, 100, 0, 100,  2);
    euler(newtonCoolingLaw, 100, 0, 100,  5);
    euler(newtonCoolingLaw, 100, 0, 100, 10);
}
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

NOTE: I'm able to successfully compile and run the executable using the terminal command `clang++`, so I know the file is fine. It has to be something wrong with Eclipse, but I don't know what.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried running `make` from a command prompt?

Comment: I don't need `make`, only to compile this one .cpp file.

Comment: You do want to be able to build your project from Eclipse, yes?
Eclipse uses `make` to build your project. The idea of running `make` from the commandline is to eliminate one potential source of problems (Eclipse). If running `make` from the command line is successful, then the problem lies with Eclipse, most likely the environment in presents to `make`. If running `make` from the command line fails the same way as when run from Eclipse, then it will be easier to alter the surrounding environment until the build works.

Comment: Ah, good call. I ran `make` and got:
`/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [Euler's Method] Error 2`

Comment: Run `make SHELL='/bin/sh -x'` and post the output. Seems like the shell didn't like the command put together by `make`. Do you have spaces in your file names or directories ? (make can't cope with them)

Comment: `make: *** No targets.  Stop.` is what I get from that input. The file name is eulerclass.cpp. Is it possible because the directory is under `Animatlab C++`?

Comment: If your project is set to generate makefiles automatically, you may need to change into the Debug or Release directory before running `make`. But yes, "Animatlab C++" as part of the full path to your project is very likely to cause problems for make. Try to rename the folder so it doesn't contain a space.

Comment: Changed the name of that folder and another than had a space but with the same error.